# Animation Texture spread out when animation on 3dsMax

Tags: textures, 3dsmax, skeletal-animation

I have a 3d model of a human biped, i did the skeleton and attached it to my 3d model with a skin modifier. But when i move his arms a part of the trunk is comming too . Is it possible to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ensure that none of the vertices in the trunk are included in the bones controlling the arms. Check out the [skin modifier documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/us/3dsmax/2012help/index.html?url=files/GUID-9596F6EF-3569-44F2-8D6C-6EB58C30BED-480.htm,topicNumber=d28e99920) and how to either modify the envelopes you're using, or manually selected the vertices controlled by the underlying bone.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, i'm on it right away ! :)